# How to access soap requested raw message in JAX-WS web-service instead of Handler?

Tags: java, soap, jdeveloper

As per the documentation of JAX-WS SOAP web-services we can access the soap message from handler, but I need that requested XML which is coming form SOAPUI or client requested data that need to be persisted in the database as per the requirement. Could you please suggest anyone one this how to access that raw XML in Web-service

Solution i found : As per my search and knowledge we can use @WebserviceProvider related stuff classes but needed to add extra WSDL code and other stuff too. but i wanted to use existing code and pass the XML from handler to web-service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Interceptor` ([documentation](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html)).

> ### Interceptors and Phases
>
> Interceptors are the fundamental processing unit inside CXF. When a
>   service is invoked, an InterceptorChain is created and invoked. Each
>   interceptor gets a chance to do what they want with the message. This
>   can include reading it, transforming it, processing headers,
>   validating the message, etc.

In your case, I think you can use an SOAP interceptor in "incoming phase" of your web service. So, when your web service will recieve a request, you can persist the request into a database.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks Michael, Could you please suggest me is there any way to pass the XML data from handler to web-service instead of writing new interceptor.

Comment: Since we already had handlers i wanted to reuse the code, I do not see any code to pass the information from handler to web-service. Please help me on this.

Comment: If you're using JAX-WS, the interceptor is the equivalent of the handler for JAX-WS. As far as I know, you can't use your handler with JAX-WS.

Comment: thanks a lot mickael i have done using soapmessagecontext object. It's working what wanted exactly..

Comment: Great. So could you please validate the answer ?

Comment: Its true that we can use handlers or interceptors to track the information, but earlier i do not have knowledge of how to pass the soap message from handler to webservice now I got to see some of the tutorials and knew that we can do that. Off cource your answer also help full for me thanks.